# Expect recognizing external program's exit command as its own

Tags: unit-testing, testing, executable, expect, exit

I am new to Expect and trying to make a tester program.
Before diving in to the problem, following is the code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect


if { [llength $argv] != 2 } {
    puts "expect tester.exp <executable> <test-case>"
    exit 1
}

set executable [lindex $argv 0]
set TEST [lindex $argv 1]
set test_cmds [split $TEST "\n"]

spawn ./$executable

set timeout 0.05
foreach test_cmd $test_cmds {
    expect "."
    send "$test_cmd\r"
    sleep 0.05
}

send_user "\r"
exit 0
```

The problem is the executable that I am trying to test has a 'exit' command itself.
In the following code, when $test_cmd becomes 'exit', I suppose it to stdin exit to the executable.
However, it seems like the 'exit' command is causing Expect to exit instead, which returns the following error.
If I do not include the 'exit' command, there is no such error.
Would there be a way to only use 'exit' to my executable but not Expect?

```
["add" "remove" "select" "show" "clone" "import" "exit"]
 splite: exit
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"send "$test_cmd\r""
    ("foreach" body line 3)
    invoked from within
"foreach test_cmd $test_cmds {
    expect "."
    send "$test_cmd\r"
    sleep 0.05
}"
    (file "tester.exp" line 18)
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact content of the 2 arguments you pass to the expect script?

Comment: Thanks for your question @glennjackman. The first argument <executable> is an external program (C++). Second argument <TEST> is a string (test commands). This expect script is called in a bash script.

Comment: Expect's `timeout` is supposed to be an `integer`. i tried and`set timeout 0.05` would be the same as `set timeout 0`.